# Assigning parameters in perpendicular axes: D-H is a must

Tags: dh-parameters, frame

So I was given a course assignment to assign frames and write D-H parameters for this robot **using only 5+1 frames (with Frame $\{5\}$ at $P$ and Frame $\{0\}$ at $O$)**.

[image: Original figure]

And I assigned them like this:

[image: My frames]

My question is:
**From Frame $\{1\}$ to Frame $\{2\}$, what are joint distances $a$ and $d$?**

The best answer I could get was 0. But obviously it should be zero for one axis and $a_1$ for the other. What's wrong?

I have read a similar question [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4610/forward-kinematics-d-h-parameters-for-perpendicular-joint-axes). But the answer points me to another method which is impossible for me.

**Edit:
No matter I put $a_1$ in $a$
$$(\alpha,a,d,\theta)=(-90^\circ,a_1,0,\theta_2-90^\circ)$$
or in $d$
$$(\alpha,a,d,\theta)=(-90^\circ,0,a_1,\theta_2-90^\circ)$$
The joint distance $a_1$ does not appear in $z$.
What it gave out is
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\sin{\theta_2} & \cos{\theta_2} & 0 & a_1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cos{\theta_2} & -\sin{\theta_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\text{    or    }
\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\sin{\theta_2} & \cos{\theta_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & a_1\\
\cos{\theta_2} & -\sin{\theta_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
Obviously, $a_1$ should appear in $Z$-translation instead!**

Comment: I am aware of the steps in D-H convention. Just that I could not get a answer that sounds reasonable to me. See Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rA9tm0gTln8) helpful when learning about the DH method.

DH is all about describing the differences between coordinate systems using rotation and translation about/along the X and Z components of the coordinate system.

**EDIT**

It seems that your frames {0} and {1} are not in the correct location if your wanting to follow the DH convention. When your on a rotation (pivoting) joint (such as the first joint), you should move up the coordinates to the next joint. That should make joint distances a and d be 0, allowing the DH convention to sufficiently describe the differences in frames.

Comment: Yes I have read this video. However, I could not find a correct answer, see the above edit.

Comment: I am anticipaing "It is 0 traveling in one axis and a1 for traveling in the other because you need to travel 0 in the x axis for frame {1} to get to frame {2} and a1 in the z axis for frame {1} to get to frame {2}." but the result I derived is not.

Comment: Ahh, I think I found out what the issue was, I have revised my answer.

Comment: So, when expressed in $\{0\}$, origins of $\{1\}$ is $(0,0,a_1)$, $\{2\}$ is $(0,a_2,a_1)$ and so on (if the joints are at initial positions as shown)?

Comment: No. Both origin {0} and origin {1} would be at the origin of {2}. When I say rotation joint, I'm taking about looking at if from a 2D perspective. If looking at it head on, the first joint would be a rotation joint (or pivot point if you prefer).

Comment: But frame 0 is set by question.

Comment: Usually to have less parameters to count for, frame 0 should be wherever your frame 1 is. However, I think the DH convention will still be followed if you just move frame 1 to where frame 2 is. This will now make frame 0 to frame 1 have a d=a1.

Comment: Oh wait. What about frame 2 and 3?  a2 is neither a or d again.

Comment: Have never solved for a robotic arm quite like this one, but try sliding frame 2 to where frame 3 is. As a general rule of thumb, If there is joint along the axis of rotation of another joint, you can probably put the frame one joint up, or one joint back depending on your configuration. Don't be disinclined in shifting the frames in this manner to see if it will work.

Sometimes I feel that selecting the frames is more of an art then anything else. :p

Comment: I will try your recommendation. For God's sake, I like manual computation much more.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the step that are in my course for using D-H convention:

## Step 1

Define the z axis of every joint

## Step 2

Define the origin frame R0 (O<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>)

## Step 3

For i in [1, n] (*n=number of joint*)

#### Step 3.1

Define O<sub>i</sub> that belongs to z<sub>i</sub>, and to the common normal to z<sub>i-1</sub> and z<sub>i</sub>

#### Step 3.2

Define x<sub>i</sub> such as x<sub>i</sub> is normal to the plan formed by z<sub>i-1</sub> and z<sub>i</sub>

#### Step 3.3

Define y<sub>i</sub> such as x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>, z<sub>i</sub> form a right handed coordinate frame

### Step 3.4

Define the frame of the tool (or the ending point of your arm)

#### Step 3.5

Find the parameters:

- Q<sub>i</sub> is at the intersection of x<sub>i</sub> and z<sub>i-1</sub>
- α_i is the angle between z<sub>i-1</sub>) and z<sub>i</sub> around x<sub>i</sub> axis
- a<sub>i</sub> is the distance |Q<sub>i</sub>,O<sub>i</sub>|
- d<sub>i</sub> is the distance |O<sub>i-1</sub>, Q<sub>i</sub>| along z<sub>i-1</sub> axis

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a nice set of steps. 3.2 needs improvement I think, since a common plane for $z_{i-1}$ and $z_i$ is a degenerate (though often seen) case.

Answer (score 1):

Each parameter is for a simple transform such that when all 4 are combined you go from one frame to the next. It can be helpful to understand each of the 4 simple transforms, and you should do that if you haven't already.